# What is it called when someone is made poor from attending too many weddings?

Tags: words

I cannot remember the phrase once taught me for when someone has become poor by attending too many weddings in Japan.

Due to usually having to pay at least 30,000 yen just to attend weddings as a guest here.

Comment: Do you think it was something like 「祝儀貧乏{しゅうぎびんぼう}」?

Comment: If I have to travel more than 2 hours for your wedding, my attendance **is** the gift.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As summea says, the term you're looking for is ご祝儀貧乏{しゅうぎびんぼう}. This is the state of poverty that results from having to attend too many weddings in too short a period of time. For those reading this that may be unaware, it is customary in Japan to give several *man* in yen (a few hundred dollars) at weddings and when babies are born, this on top of travel costs and whatever else it may cost to participate in a wedding. When many of these obligations pile up in a short period of time it can create a rough financial situation for those who would like to attend and also honor the traditions of giving money. The internet is rife with people troubled about this:

http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1227793932
http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1045614140

Among others!

Comment: ひええ・・・結婚・出産ラッシュ、こわっ！